# Making my website work on different screen sizes

Tags: css, responsive

this is the first website that I created,
and I don't want to bother making my website responsive, I didn't add the viewport tag (that makes it responsive). However, for some reason, it resizes the webpage even though I don't want it to.

I just don't want my website to collapse on different screen sizes.

I hope you guys understood what I mean, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use something like bootstrap or flexbox when creating your website?
If yes, that might be your problem since these will make your website more responsive when used correctly. if you dont want your website to resize, you can use flexbox flex-shrink or just use width and height on objects in pixels instead of %.

Hope this helps you out a bit,

Ramon.

Comment: No i did not use flex box or bootstrap for doing my website.

Comment: Okay, But did using pixels on width and height work for you?